# How do I retrieve the stored password from Thunderbird?

Tags: macos, thunderbird

I am running TB 3.0.1 on Mac OS X. The password for my email account is saved and I can't remember it. Is there anyway to retrieve it in clear text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tools > Options > Security > Passwords > Saved Passwords > Show Passwords

Answer (score 7):

These days (Thunderbird 24) it is:

Thunderbird > Preferences > Security > Passwords > Saved Passwords > Show Passwords > Confirm - Yes